# Remove extra space present in bottom the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

we need to remove the extra space present in bottom of the `table`.

at present, we have like this :

[image]

but we want like this :

[image]

**css**

```css
.wk_mp_body td {
    background: #282828;
}

.wk_mp_body td {

    padding: 5px 7px;
}

tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}

table {
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    empty-cells: show;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="border wk_mp_list_table">
    <thead>
      <tr id="wk_mp_tr_heading">
        <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
        <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Date') ?></span></th>
        <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Product Status') ?></span></th>
        <th><span>&nbsp;</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="wk_mp_body">
      <tr>
        <td><input class="input-text" name="s" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__(' type="text">' value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('s')?>"/&gt;</td>
        <td><span class="wk_mp_td_span"><?php echo $helper->__('') ?> <input class="input-text" id="special_from_date" name="from_date" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__(' value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('from_date')?>">'/&gt;</span> <span class="wk_mp_td_span"><?php echo $helper->__('') ?> <input class="input-text" id="special_to_date" name="to_date" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__(' value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('to_date')?>">'/&gt;</span></td>
        <td><select class="input-text" name="prostatus" style="height:35px;">
          <option value="">
            <?php echo $helper->__('All') ?>
          </option>
          <option value="1">
            <?php echo $helper->__('Approved') ?>
          </option>
          <option value="2">
            <?php echo $helper->__('Unapproved') ?>
          </option>
        </select></td>
        <td><button class="button" style="background:#fc6c0b;" title="Save" type="submit"><span><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Submit') ?></span></span></span></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

please help me to find solution

Comment: Can you add the corresponding HTML ?

Comment: Or, even better, prepare a fiddle for us: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Pugazh i added html part, if possible i will try jsfiddle.net.

Comment: You can also use the Stack Snippets feature (icon that looks like a page with `<>` on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `td`'s which by default have `vertical-align:baseline`, so all you need is to set the `vertical-align` to `middle`

```css
tbody td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: black;
}
thead th {
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}
.wk_mp_td_span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
button span {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
button span span {
  padding: 9px 15px 8px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font: 12px/29px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 2px 8px !important;
  width: 80%;
}
select {
  height: 35px
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="border wk_mp_list_table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="wk_mp_tr_heading">
      <th><span>Product Name</span>
      </th>
      <th><span>Date</span>
      </th>
      <th><span>Product Status</span>
      </th>
      <th><span>&nbsp;</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="wk_mp_body">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="input-text" name="s" placeholder="Search by product name" type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td><span class="wk_mp_td_span"><input class="input-text hasDatepicker" id="special_from_date" name="from_date" placeholder="From:" value=""></span>  <span class="wk_mp_td_span"><input class="input-text hasDatepicker" id="special_to_date" name="to_date" placeholder="To:" value=""></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="input-text" name="prostatus">
          <option value="">
            All
          </option>
          <option value="1">
            Approved
          </option>
          <option value="2">
            Unapproved
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="button" style="background:#fc6c0b;" title="Save" type="submit"><span><span><span>Submit</span></span>
          </span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry , it did't worked me to remove completely , please check [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/)

Comment: before it was like this : http://prnt.sc/b677zd  & now its like this : http://prnt.sc/b6785x

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe sorry for the delay, but your [ScreenShot](http://prnt.sc/b6785x) shows me exactly what you want, having the inputs aligned vertically with the black table. what you want more?

Comment: if you check the question , you can check 2nd image. there space is very less. please observe clearly , you will find the difference.

Comment: can you please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269248/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two `.wk_mp_body td` css classes? Combine into one.

You have 5px 7px of padding, try removing it.

Comment: please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/) & login with email : kidsdial4@gmail.com , password : totaltoys99 and help me

Comment: Just remove this:    .wk_mp_body td {      padding: 5px 7px; }

Comment: if i do that, it will remove background color between textboxes.

Comment: Then add a smaller value, such as 2px 5px or until you have your ideal spacing

Comment: i tried but still it not reducing fully.  i want some thing like [this](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myorderhistory/)

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two classes (.wk_mp_body td)
IE:

```
.wk_mp_body td {
background: #282828;
padding: 5px 7px;
}
```

And reduce the number on the padding.